# I18n translation with gem grape for ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-grape, grape-api

I start to translate my database with the `globalize3` gem that works well and when I change url it will look for me the data of the language like this `Localhost:3000/en/post`

I created an API with the Grape gem but I would like to do the same as the site which means `localhost:300/en/api/v1/momuments`

But no data goes out and I do not know if I have configured `Grape` for who gets me the content according to the languages.

Here is the configuration of my routes.

```
scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|nl/ do
 resources :categories
 resources :monuments
 root 'pages#index'
 devise_for :users

 # API+API Documentation
 mount Api::Sap::Api, at: "api"
 mount GrapeSwaggerRails::Engine, at: "api/documentation"
end
```

Thanks

Comment: can you try `mount Api::Sap::Api, at: '/api'`

Comment: His walk is half because his me makes a random on the received data and it is weird that it is not planned or my configuration is bad